Understanding Indexing a DataFrame with a MultiIndex using Slicers for each level
Can someone help me understand why the Example B works, but Example A throws an Error? I am using python-3.11.2 along with pandas==2.2.2 and numpy==2.0.1.
One can find the below example in the Pandas documentation for MultiIndex Link
Setup Code, from Pandas Documentation
In [51]: def mklbl(prefix, n):
   ....:     return ["%s%s" % (prefix, i) for i in range(n)]
   ....: 

In [52]: miindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
   ....:     [mklbl("A", 4), mklbl("B", 2), mklbl("C", 4), mklbl("D", 2)]
   ....: )
   ....: 

In [53]: micolumns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
   ....:     [("a", "foo"), ("a", "bar"), ("b", "foo"), ("b", "bah")],
   ....:     names=["lvl0", "lvl1"]
   ....: )
   ....: 

In [54]: dfmi = (
   ....:     pd.DataFrame(
   ....:         np.arange(len(miindex) * len(micolumns)).reshape(
   ....:             (len(miindex), len(micolumns))
   ....:         ),
   ....:         index=miindex,
   ....:         columns=micolumns,
   ....:     )
   ....:     .sort_index()
   ....:     .sort_index(axis=1)
   ....: )
   ....: 

In [57]: idx = pd.IndexSlice
In [61]: mask = dfmi[("a", "foo")] > 200
In [62]: dfmi.loc[idx[mask, :, ["C1", "C3"]], idx[:, "foo"]]

However,
Example A: dfmi.loc[idx[mask, 'B0', 'C0'], idx[:, "foo"]] throws an Error,
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 1
----> 1 dfmi.loc[idx[mask, 'B0', 'C0'], idx[:, "foo"]]

... 

File ~/my_python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py:3545, in MultiIndex.get_locs(self, seq)
   3543         indexer &= lvl_indexer
   3544         if not np.any(indexer) and np.any(lvl_indexer):
-> 3545             raise KeyError(seq)
   3547 # empty indexer
   3548 if indexer is None:

KeyError: (A0  B0  C0  D0    False
            D1    False
        C1  D0    False
            D1    False
        C2  D0    False
                  ...  
A3  B1  C1  D1     True
        C2  D0     True
            D1     True
        C3  D0     True
            D1     True
Name: (a, foo), Length: 64, dtype: bool, 'B0', 'C0')

whereas
Example B: dfmi.loc[idx[mask, 'B0', 'C0':'C0'], idx[:, "foo"]] doesn't. It returns an empty dataset (which is the desired result).
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [(a, foo), (b, foo)]
Index: []

This happens in spite of the fact that they are almost identical statements, since label slicing includes end points.

Just FYI, I mentioned before that I'm getting an error for both examples on Pandas 2.0.3, but there seems to be a bug where mask changes even though none of the code here should mutate it. Specifically, the True values (some or all) change to False.
